# How to send elasticsearch ILM policie to elasticsearch api using docker?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I am trying to set elasticsearch ilm policy when logstash container starts. So i need to send an api request to elasticsearch. But the problem is, that how can i do this? If i put some curl in dockerfile, it could mean nothing, because elasticsearch and logstash are building and not running. Anyway to resolve this?

Comment: Why not simply using the ILM settings of the `elasticsearch` Logstash output?

Comment: Because I want to edit the policy using env vars using docker compose